# give two function in one button in Yii framework

Tags: javascript, php, button, yii

I have a question about Yii framework, i have problem with submit button, i want to given two fungsi save and update in one submit button, can anyone tell me how to set that function on form ?

```
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
```

i change 'Save' with 'Update' it's still have error Primary key added, how i can create two function update and save in one push button ?

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new TblUasUts;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['TblUasUts']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUasUts'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->nim_mhs));
    }
            if(isset($_POST['TblUasUts'])
    {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUasUts'];
            if($model->update())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->nim_mhs));
     }                
    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicates -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339291/replace-data-from-same-id-user-in-yii-framework

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you can use something like :

```
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update'); ?>
</div>
```

As far as processing different actions on the backend code, there are a few options, for example, you could :-

- Direct your form to different URLs
- Set a (hidden) field (for example ID) and parse for that.
- Use the default action from the activeForm, which directs back to the invoking action, for example actionCreate(), or actionUpdate()

In light of your updates, please extend your controller as per my initial suggestion to have another action actionUpdate()

The main difference between the actionCreate(), or actionUpdate() actions is that the Create action create a new (empty) TblUasUts object, while the Update action populates the TblUasUts object from the database.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new TblUasUts;
    ...
    ... Do things with $model ...
    ...
    $model->save();

}

public function actionUpdate
{
    // The id of the existing entry is passed in the url. for example
    // ...http:// .... /update/id/10
    //
    $model = TblUasUts::model()->findByPK($_GET['id']);
    ...
    ... Do things with $model ...
    ...
    $model->save();

}
```

Comment: i still getting error like this, how i can fix it ?
CDbCommand gagal menjalankan statementSQL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '123456' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: It is impossible to help you with the amount of information you have provided. At least show us the code to process the form data and save the record, because it is at this point where the problem is happening. Until then, you are on your own.

Comment: i have been update my question, i still confused to using that's two function save and update in one button

Comment: You have one view, used for Create and Update, when you call actionCreate(), the view is created with form action 'Create'. when you call actionUpdate(), the same view is created with form action 'Update'. Therefore: 1 view , 2 actions. Please read the tutorial on the YII site This is explained there.