# Replace data from same id user in Yii framework

Tags: php, button, yii, submit

How I can fix this error? I have problem replace data from same id this is my _from:

```
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update'); ?>
</div>
```

and this is my Controller action Create :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new TblUasUts;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['TblUasUts']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUasUts'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->nim_mhs));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

this is what I'm getting as an error:

> CDbCommand gagal menjalankan statementSQL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2010140360' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Please clarify your problem. It is currently completely not possible to understand what problem you have.

Comment: i have getting repair my question

Comment: Hello Learn Again could you please show your database schema so that we can help upto extreme level.

Comment: Why are you posting duplicates of the same question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276763/give-two-function-in-one-button-in-yii-framework

Answer (score 1):

It happens becouse you try to save element with existing Primary Key id. if you want to update existing entry in DB you should load ActiveRecord from DB(TblUasUts::model()->findByPk). Also you can unset field id from into $_POST array and create new row in DB every time.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
$model=new TblUasUts;

// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['TblUasUts']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['TblUasUts']['id']) && $_POST['TblUasUts']['id']) {
        $model = TblUasUts::model()->findByPk((int)$_POST['TblUasUts']['id']);
    }

    $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUasUts'];
    if($model->update())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->nim_mhs));
}

$this->render('update',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

}

Comment: it's can be update because it's new record, how i can fix it ?

Comment: Insert unset($_POST['TblUasUts']['id']); before $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUasUts'];

Comment: if(isset($_POST['TblUasUts']))
{

    if (isset($_POST['TblUasUts']['id']) && $_POST['TblUasUts']['id']) {
        $model = TblUasUts::model()->findByPk((int)$_POST['TblUasUts']['id']) ?: new TblUasUts;
        unset($_POST['TblUasUts']['id'])
    }

    $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUasUts'];
    if($model->update())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->nim_mhs));
}

Answer (score 0):

Remove save with update:

```
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update'); ?>
</div>

and this is my Controller action Create :

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new TblUasUts;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['TblUasUts']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUasUts'];
        if($model->update())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->nim_mhs));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Also check have you made your ID field auto increment and primary as well.

Comment: You get error because of following reasons: 1) Incorrectly define PK or model is not able to load new instance.

Comment: i made primary or id not auto increment but primary i set like user id, i won't to save if not have data but will be update if have data in db, but using one submit button

Comment: You need to make id increment otherwise how model can create record with same id here. If you need to record with same name use query method in yii